# KeyListener class becomes unresponsive after game being reset

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, keylistener

I am writing a simple snake app in java i have a gamePanel that contains the game and its being added to the JFrame Window class, when I first start the game the keylistener works perfectly but when the game is lost (when button pressed, the game resets itself but the keylistener becomes unresponsive), i do not see any reason why it should become unresponsive, i do not do anything to it

```
class Window extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2542001418764869760L;
    private final ButtonPanel buttonPanel;
    private GamePanel gamePanel;
    private ThreadsController c;

    // now size of the game can change only by modifiying this width and height

    public JFrame getFrame() {
        return this;
    }

    public JPanel getGamePanel() {
        return gamePanel;
    }

    public JPanel getButtonPanel() {
        return buttonPanel;
    }

    public Window() throws FileNotFoundException {

        this.setTitle("Snake");
        this.setSize(300, 300);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        gamePanel = new GamePanel();
        this.buttonPanel = new ButtonPanel(this, c);

        this.add(new TopPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);

        this.add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.setVisible(true);
        c = new ThreadsController(gamePanel.getSnakeDepartPosition());
        this.buttonPanel.getExit().addActionListener(
                new ButtonActionListener(this, c));
        this.buttonPanel.getNewGame().addActionListener(
                new ButtonActionListener(this, c));

        c.start();
        this.addKeyListener(new KeyboardListener());
        this.setFocusable(true);
    }

    private class KeyboardListener extends KeyAdapter {

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                // if it's not the opposite direction
                if (ThreadsController.directionSnake != Directions.LEFT)
                    ThreadsController.directionSnake = Directions.RIGHT;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                if (ThreadsController.directionSnake != Directions.BOTTOM)
                    ThreadsController.directionSnake = Directions.TOP;
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                if (ThreadsController.directionSnake != Directions.RIGHT)
                    ThreadsController.directionSnake = Directions.LEFT;
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                if (ThreadsController.directionSnake != Directions.TOP)
                    ThreadsController.directionSnake = Directions.BOTTOM;
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }    
    }

}


here is the action listener

    public class ButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {

    private Window frame;
    private ThreadsController t;

    public ButtonActionListener(Window frame, ThreadsController t) {
        this.frame = frame;
        this.t = t;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent clickedButton) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*
         * t.setAlive(false);
         * 
         * frame.getContentPane().remove(frame.getGamePanel());
         * 
         * 
         * 
         * frame.add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER); frame.setVisible(true);
         */GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();
        gamePanel.addKeyListener(new KeyboardListenner());
        frame.add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        t = new ThreadsController(new Tuple(10, 10));
        t.start();    
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KeyEvents are only generated for the component that has focus.

When you click on the button the button now has focus NOT your "GamePanel". You need to use:

```
gamePanel.requestFocusInWindow();
```

AFTER the frame is visible.

However, that will not fix the problem because you can't just add a new "GamePanel" to the frame because your content pane will now contain two GamePanels. Swing will paint the components if the reverse order that they were added to the frame. So you new GamePanel will be painted first and then the old GamePanel will be painted on top. So you will need to remove the old GamePanel BEFORE adding the new GamePanel.

Or, a better approach if you want to reset the game is to have a "Reset" method in your GamePanel that resets the game. Don't k

Comment: cool thanx for the answer, however if has to be called frame.requestFocusInWindow(); i just didn't know about the entire focus business here, that was a great hint. apparently Panels are not focusable at all.

Comment: The OP is relying on the side effect of `BorderLayout` which will only layout the last component added to a given position, however, they are not disposing of pre-existing controller, which would be of more concern (IMHO)...not to mention key bindings ;)

Comment: @Jenny, panels are not focusable by default but they can be made focusable. The normal recommendation is to use `Key Bindings` so you don't have focus issues. Check out [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more information.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, yes, it will only layout the last component added, however because of ZOrder logic only the first component added will be visible since it is painted last (and it still have valid location/size information, assuming the frame has not been resized). That is why I suggested the first game panel needed to be removed before you add the second game panel.

Comment: @camickr Oh, agree with removing the first panel, no issue with that

Comment: @camickr Tested, wouldn't have thought of that, fair point about the z-ordering...